# Is there a way to match multiple words in regex for google sheets in one single expression?

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I'm looking for some regex solutions for Google Sheets to match several words within a text in any order in one single expression.
I have looked in Stack but all I have found is solutions that either don't work in Sheets or use several regex expressions, one for each word to find.
I don't want to use the regex ```|``` (```OR```) operand, instead, I want to use the ```AND``` operand, to get results that are more restrictive.
As far as I know, in regex environments other than Sheets, to find several strings (i.d. word1 and word2), no matter their order, I would use ```(?=.*word1)(?=.*word2)```, but this expression is not allowed in a Google Sheets environment.
Instead, in Sheets it seems that I need one expression for each word that we want to find and join them all with an ```*```, so the formula gets very long if the list of strings is long. Resulting something such as:
```=regexmatch(a1,"word1")*regexmatch(a1,"word2")```
My question is whether is there a way to match several words in a paragraph in and additive way, no matter the order, and inside one single regex expression.
Thank you very much.

Comment: No, it is not possible without lookaheads. RE2 is too limited in regex features.

Comment: There is a kind of a workaround that does not scale, i.e. `word1.*word2|word2.*word1`, etc. For three words, it is still feasible, but will become even clumsier with more words to support. And that becomes less and less efficient.

Comment: I see. The more words, the more combinatory possibilities. Thanks